# Joomla modules & show-positions not displaying

Tags: templates, joomla, module, position

I am using an install of Joomla 1.5.26 and have installed and defaulted the JTouch template (version 1.5.2-stable).  I found that the `?tp=1` command at the end of the the home page's address works perfectly (shows module positions, etc.) but this command is not working on any of the other pages.

Also, probably along the same lines, I have a module that I would like to activate on a page other than the home page (at position `jtouch-top`) so I assigned this module to the menu item for the page I want and it still isn't displaying...Even the menu item shows that this module should be active...This process works correctly if I want the module to display on the home page.

What about this template could be breaking these Joomla functions for every page but the home?

The address for this site is: `http://198.1.124.170/~lawson2/` (this is on a development server so does not have an actual www address yet.)

Comment: It's nice looking site, but why on earth are you wasting time developing for a Joomla version that's no longer supported for security bugs? Also, I got the mobile version in Firefox on my Win7 desktop pc.

Comment: agreed with @isherwood - You should start your site using Joomla 2.5.9 as it's the latest long term release.

Comment: I normally would START a site with 2.5.x, Unfortunately I'm working with an old site that is already built in Joomla 1.5.  I'm just trying to develop a mobile template for it without having to redo everything into a later version...I was trying to save time, but maybe my time would be better spent scrapping a mobile template until we upgrade to a later version of Joomla?  Thanks for the constructive criticism!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question, URL parameters are separated by &, not ?. SO won't let me post an IP link, so try this after the first slash:

```
?jtouchTemplateSelector=yoo_enterprise&jtpl=yoo_enterprise&tp=1
```

Update: Here's a direct link: http://tinyurl.com/a4uc6yc

As for your followup questions, it's hard to say without more information. Is the module published?

Update: Knowing that you're troubleshooting the mobile template specifically, I'd look at position mapping. In my experience, template developers don't necessarily load the same positions for mobile, and some may not even exist. RocketTheme, for example, has specific mapping built into their control panel.

Comment: Yes the modules I'm wanting to show are published and assigned to the menu items for the pages that I'm trying to display on.  Also, I'm trying to develop for the _jtouch_ (mobile) template, not the _yoo-enterprise_ (desktop) template.  I'm open to any other ideas to help diagnose this.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @isherwood, I've always used the '?tp=1' in the past but in this case the '&tp=1' DOES allow me to see module positions for the jtouch template.  I'm guessing this is because I don't have the SEF URLs turned on and I already have a '?' in my URLs? 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=262&tp=1'

Comment: That's correct. ? indicates the beginning of the URL params, and & separates multiple params.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing this?

http://www.lawsonsp.com/lawson-equipment?tp=1

I can see the template positions.

Comment: I unfortunately still have the old absolute links back to the original site with the functioning desktop template (shown in the link you posted) but I am trying to focus just on the non-www development site with the mobile template.